# How to parse pages under login/password with Beautifulsoup in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I would like to make a parser with the following functionality:

1. Person inputs his login and password in html-form
2. Parser connects to closed pages with this password and login
3. Parse all necessary information
4. Create a csv file with the data

So my question is: how to make step 2 with `beautifulsoup`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Mechanize package for logging into a site and then accessing which ever closed pages you require. You can then pass the page(s) to  beautifulsoup for parsing.

[Here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-mechanize-cheat-sheet) is a cheat sheet for Mechanize.